# Some special Apache Camel functions are not available

Tags: apache-camel

trying to use this route:
from("activemq:profiles").aggregate(header("cheese")).batchSize(30).bean(ProfilesQueueService, "saveContacts")

Fails with:

No signature of method: org.apache.camel.model.RouteType.aggregate() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.camel.builder.ValueBuilder) values: [header(cheese)]

Using apache camel 1.6.1
I've checked RouteTypes.java. Indeed there's no aggregate() method.
However, this docs says it must work:
http://camel.apache.org/aggregator.html

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Camel 1.x some of the EIP patterns is using a slightly different name.

Its called aggregator in 1.x

You can see the difference in the Apache Camel 2.0 release notes
http://camel.apache.org/camel-200-release.html
in the section - Notable changes to DSL